# Netbeans 7.0.1 not opening

Tags: 11.10, netbeans

I am working in Netbeans on Ubuntu for the last 4 months. But today when I opened Netbeans, it just got stuck in the Ubuntu launcher bar at the left side of screen.

I have my project pending in Netbeans (which is not opening). I am stuck in this problem.
I also rebooted Ubuntu a number of times, still the same. I can't open Netbeans.
Why is this happening? What is the cause of this problem? What should I do?

tried $gksu netbeans, nothing happens, $ prompt shown again.

Comment: try to launch it from terminal , is it showing any errors ?

Comment: sorry but how do i start it from the terminal?

Comment: it gives following error (gksu:4280): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally re-installed netbeans and restarted the system before trying to open it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Netbeans manually in 11.10 (or older), you'll find out that netbeans cannot start with the following error:

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

This is because the path for the Java Runtime Environment has slightly changed. Before, it was something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre`. In Ubuntu 12.04, this path has become is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-`**amd64**`/jre/`. (or `i386` if you have a 32-bit OS)

To solve this problem without reinstalling Netbeans, open the file `netbeans-7.1.1/etc/netbeans.conf` (the path for 7.0.1 should not differ a lot). Find the line:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
```

and replace it by:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

The next time you start netbeans, the issue should be gone.

Comment: well i havent upgraded to 12.04, anyways i have reinstalled netbeans to make it work

Comment: That's /etc/netbeans.conf I take it, that one should modify?

Comment: @Sam This answer was made with a manual installation in mind, I presume that Ubuntu have packaged netbeans properly with the correct path, but if you experience the error as written in the answer, you can of course try it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Terminal, run `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, and try again.

Comment: did so, and tried $gksu netbeans, nothing happens now, $ prompt shown again :(

Comment: i had tried to open with icon only previously, the netbeans loads and gets stuck in ubuntu launcher

Comment: restarted my system and did the icon launch and gksu netbeans, still the same, what should i do? my work is stuck up in this

Comment: is reinstallation the only option? coz i dont want to do it

Comment: you getting the same error ?